# Debian 7.5 Wine аудио

Tags: аудио, debian, wine

Поставил себе вчера Debian, все пока идет нормально. Решил запустить игрушку, виндовую, ввел в консолько, все сразу запустилось но звук скрепит ли, трещит ли, зашел в настройки Wine, потыкался там, при нажатие Проверка звука, получаю тот же скрип. Как я понимаю драйвер на самом дебе pulseaudio, в вайне указано, драйвер: winealso.drv в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте под Вайн кодеки вендовые подтянуть. А вообще-то это очень древняя проблема - со звуком.

ЗЫ: С Алсой будут те же проблемы. Тут, похоже, дело именно в кодеках.